# quantlib; black scholes process drift issue

Tags: c++, quantlib

I have a question about GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess::drift.
Below is the code.

```
  Real GeneralizedBlackScholesProcess::drift(Time t, Real x) const {
         Real sigma = diffusion(t,x);
         // we could be more anticipatory if we know the right dt
         // for which the drift will be used
         Time t1 = t + 0.0001;
         return riskFreeRate_->forwardRate(t,t1,Continuous,NoFrequency,true)
              - dividendYield_->forwardRate(t,t1,Continuous,NoFrequency,true)
              - 0.5 * sigma * sigma;
     }
```

In black scholes process with timegrid(t0, t1, t2, ...),
I think that forward rate between timegrid is needed such as f_to~t1, f_t1~t2, f_t2~t3.

But in Quantlib's drift, forward rate between tn, tn + 0.0001 is calculated.

I think this is wrong, forward rate between tn, tn + dt is correct

Why do not Quantlib's drift require dt?